# ¿Cómo puedo redireccionar tras hacer login con jQuery y Ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, html5, ajax

Estoy realizando un proyecto de login y gestión de usuarios en el cual estoy aprendiendo jQuery y Ajax.

Tengo la funcionalidad básica, es decir, un usuario hace login y sale un mensaje de usuario y/o contraseña incorrecta si no es válido.

**Lo que quiero conseguir** (estoy buscando modos de hacerlo), es poder redireccionar a la página de usuario una vez el logueo es correcto. (No sé si tengo que hacerlo desde php, o bien podría usar jQuery).

Este es mi index.php:

```
<?php
  require_once 'php/logOut.php';
  session_start();
  if(isset($_SESSION['userSession'])){
    if(!empty($_SESSION['userSession'])){
      header("Location: models/userPanel.php");
    }
  }
  if (isset($_GET['logOut'])) {
    logOut();
  }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <!-- CSS imports -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
    <!-- JQuery include -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="js/loginForm.js"></script> -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Login</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Navigation Bar content -->
    <nav class="navBar">
      <ul>
        <li><a class="hover" href="index.php">Index</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <!-- Body content -->
    <div class="bodyContainer">
      <!-- Form -->
      <div class="formContainer">
        <p class="formTitle">Login form</p>
        <form id="loginForm" method="post">
          <div class="formDataContainer">
            <div id="error"><!-- Error will be shown here ! --></div>
            <label for="userMail"><span class="labelText">Email</span></label>
            <input type="email" placeholder="Enter Username" name="userMail" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false">
            <label for="psw"><span class="labelText">Password</span></label>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false">
            <button type="submit" id="btnLogin" name="btnLogin">Sing in</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        $('#error').fadeOut();
        $('form[id=\'loginForm\']').on('submit', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#error").fadeOut();
            var data = $(this).serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST', url: 'php/loginProcess.php', data: data, beforeSend: function(){
                    $('#error').fadeOut();
                    $('#btnLogin').html('Sending ...');
                }, success: function(response){
                    if (response == 'ok'){
                        $('#btnLogin').html('Signing In ...');
                        setTimeout(' window.location.href = "models/userPanel.php"; ', 4000);
                    }else{
                        $('#error').fadeIn(1000, function(){
                        $('#error').html(response);
                        $('#btnLogin').html('Sign In');
                      });
                    }
                },
            });
            return false;
        });
        /* login submit */
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Y este, mi controlador de PHP:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  require_once 'dbConfig.php';
  $query = "SELECT idUser, name, surname, mail, level, password
            FROM users
            WHERE mail = ? AND password = ?";
  // TODO recoger datos
  if(isset($_POST["userMail"]) && isset($_POST["psw"])){
    if(!empty($_POST["userMail"]) && !empty($_POST["psw"])){
      // TODO comprobamos la base de datos
      // Clean obtained data
      $userMail = $mysqli->real_escape_string(trim($_POST["userMail"]));
      $passwd = $mysqli->real_escape_string(trim($_POST["psw"]));
      // Crypt the Password
      $password = md5($passwd);
      // Attempt to prepare the query
      if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)){
        if($stmt->bind_param("ss", $userMail, $password)){
          $stmt->execute();
          // Obtain the result
          $result = $stmt->get_result();
          // If there is no result, we will show an error message
          if($result->num_rows === 0){
            echo "Invalid username or password";
          }else{
            // If we have data, we will check again the obtained data
            $row = $result->fetch_array();
            if($row["mail"] === $userMail && $row["password"] === $password){
              // If correct, we will log in the user
              $_SESSION['userSession']['mail'] = $row['mail'];
              $_SESSION['userSession']['name'] = $row['name'];
              $_SESSION['userSession']['surname'] = $row['surname'];
              // TODO redirect
            }
          }
          $mysqli->close();
        }else{
          // TODO handle error

        }
      }
    }
  }
?>
```

Tal y como se puede ver, tengo un TODO para la redirección en el archivo de control de PHP pero no sé cómo podría hacerlo. He intentado soluciones vía jQuery y no funcionan.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

**Edit**

Tras ver la respuesta, he intentado hacer el código como me comentan pero ahora la redirección no se efectúa correctamente.

```
$('#error').fadeOut();
        $('form[id=\'loginForm\']').on('submit', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#error").fadeOut();
            var data = $(this).serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST', url: 'php/loginProcess.php', data: data, beforeSend: function(){
                    $('#error').fadeOut();
                    $('#btnLogin').html('Sending ...');
                }, success: function(response){
                    if (response == 'ok'){
                        $('#btnLogin').html('Signing In ...');
                        window.location("models/userPanel.php");
                        setTimeout(' window.location.href = "models/userPanel.php"; ', 4000);
                    }else{
                        $('#error').fadeIn(1000, function(){
                        $('#error').html(response);
                        $('#btnLogin').html('Sign In');
                      });
                    }
                },
            });
            return false;
        });
```

Comment: La página de usuario sería, por ejemplo, paginaweb.com/usuario ? O paginaweb.com/portal.php?user=usuario. Algo así, no? Con PHP puedes usar el header('Location: http://www.example.com/');

Comment: Sería paginaweb.com/models/userPanel.php

Comment: En donde esta tu dataType en el ajax? Y en el if(response == 'ok') de donde viene ese 'ok', no lo veo en el php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En la línea dónde está el TODO, tienes que agregar una como la que sigue:

```
// TODO redirect
header("Location: paginaweb.com/models/userPanel.php");
exit();
```

Editada: Esto no va a funcionar porque el header location se realiza bajo la petición ajax y no sobre la página del usuario. Para poder redirigir tras la llamada ajax, se debe hacer un window.location en la parte success o done del ajax:

```
$('#btnLogin').html('Signing In ...');
window.location("paginaweb.com/models/userPanel.php");
```

Comment: Buenas. He intentado hacer esa solución con anterioridad pero desde el login el botón se queda en modo Sending...

Comment: Cierto, edito la respuesta para indicar que se debe hacer en la parte javascript justo al completar el ajax.

Comment: En este caso, he usado el código que me has indicado, pero no hace nada.

Mira en mi edit para ver lo que he hecho.

Gracias por tu tiempo.

Comment: ¿Te sale algún error? mira en la consola del inspector de elementos de la web, deberías ver un error.

Comment: No sale ningún error. Lo que es muy raro. Hace lo mismo que sin poner la línea de código que me has indicado.

Comment: Prueba a reemplazar la línea por un alert, es como si nunca llegara allí. Lo que me hace pensar que puedes intentar cambiar success por done, mira un ejemplo: http://www.falconmasters.com/jquery/peticiones-ajax-jquery/

Comment: No llega al alert dentro del success. Fuera si llega.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75770/discussion-between-ramon-guardia-and-track3r).

Comment: Estoy en el chat